# C# consuming a wcf Request method in a Restful way

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, xsd

We have been provided with a couple of xsd's from a third party. I have used the XSD Utility to create some classes. One of these classes is called 'GetProducts' and it has one method on it called Request.

The idea is that the 3rd party will call this method and then we need to act on the information that it has sent via this method.

in my ServiceContract class how do I consume this method in a Restful way? I'm not sure how I should declare the operationcontract. Can anybody offer a good code sample. Here's the method that has been generated from the xsd:

```
public partial class GetProducts
{

    private ProductsRequest requestField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ProductsRequest Request
    {
        get { return this.requestField; }
        set { this.requestField = value; }
    }
}`
```

Comment: I could not clearly understand what you want to do... is this  WcfService->GetProducts->Resquest->call a 3rd party restful service, or 3rd party->WcfService->GetProducts->Request->call some restful service?

Comment: Basically it's a comparison site. So the comparison site will send us some basic details of the product by calling the 'getProducts' method that they have supplied us via the xsd. I then need to use this information to go get complete details and then send the information back. Since this is to be a WCF service. I have taken the XSD supplied and used the XSD utility which has created a bunch of C# classes. So I need to write a Service contract that will invoke when they make the request by sending basic details.